# error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'WorldAnchor' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEngine.XR.WSA' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: unity-game-engine, compiler-errors, azure-spatial-anchors

I used remote rendering model and add it to my project but i got a lot of errors. And now these 2 errors stay and I cannot find a solution.

When I made a new project only to test the remote rendering it works fine but when I add it to my project, many errors appear. How do I fix these errors?

> 1-  Library\PackageCache\com.microsoft.azure.spatial-anchors-sdk.core@2.7.2\Runtime\Scripts\SpatialAnchorExtensions.cs(21,41): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'WorldAnchor' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEngine.XR.WSA' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>
> 2- Library\PackageCache\com.microsoft.azure.spatial-anchors-sdk.core@2.7.2\Runtime\Scripts\CloudNativeAnchor.cs(13,41): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'WorldAnchor' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEngine.XR.WSA' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I am using the last version of unity 2020.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are using Azure Spatial Anchors SDK version 2.7 and according to [Building in Unity with Azure Spatial Anchors | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spatial-anchors/unity-overview) you need to use Unity 2019.4 or update Azure Spatial Anchors SDK version to 2.9 or later.

> The Azure Spatial Anchors SDK versions 2.8 or earlier do not support the Unity XR Plug-in Framework and should be configured in Unity 2019.4 (LTS)
>
> The Azure Spatial Anchors SDK for version 2.9 or later should be configured in Unity 2020.3 (LTS) with the Unity XR Plug-in Framework